# Manipulating Tilemap color component in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

So, I am trying to make a script that changes the color and transparency of certain tile maps to show what floor of a structure I am looking at. Essentially, floors that are below me appear much darker, and floors above will be mostly transparent, and the floor i am viewing is the default color. I would like to change the color of every tile on the tilemap at once. By having the actual tilemaps be child objects of the grid of that floor, I could just change the color of the tilemaps, on the child objects, like so

```
if (activeFloor == thisFloor)
{
    isActiveFloor = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        floorChildren[i].GetComponent<TilemapRenderer>().sortingOrder = 2 + i;
        floorChildren[i].GetComponent<Tilemap>().color = defaultColor;
    }
}
else
{
    isActiveFloor = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        floorChildren[i].GetComponent<TilemapRenderer>().sortingOrder = -2 + i;
        if(thisFloor>activeFloor)
        {
            floorChildren[i].GetComponent<Tilemap>().color = nearlyTransparent;
        }
        else
        {
            floorChildren[i].GetComponent<Tilemap>().color = blackedOutColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt seem to do much. It does change the sorting order, so the active layer will be in the front, but it looks weird without some color correction to lower and upper floors. I know that SetColor exists, but from unity documentation it seems that it only affects one tile, meaning i would have to make a ridiculous for loop or something just to do this, when just getting the ().color to change would be way easier.

EDIT: so i have found something interesting. On the tilemap, when I enter play mode, it always sets the color of the tilemap to (191, 191, 191, 255). This is not the color it is supposed to be set to, and none of the color values in this script are that value. Even setting its color in the inspector, it will still change it to that value. And i can set it to the proper color in play mode in the inspector, but pressing a button that changes the floor (meaning the code above will run again), will always set it back to that color value. The code here is changing something, im just not sure why it would set it to this specific value.

Comment: if `.color` or `.material.color` isn't working for you and you are sure that you addressing your object correctly, you can use `LayerMask.NameToLayer("NewLayer")` to change the layer of the object and have the layer decides the color for its hierarchy children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for some reason, setting the color like so

```
private Color defaultColor = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
private Color blackedOutColor = new Color(30, 30, 30, 255);
private Color nearlyTransparent = new Color(255, 255, 255, 50);
```

does not work. This is because when using **new Color(r,g,b,a);** the value is actually supposed to be set between 0 and 1, so 0 is the minimum value that the color can have, and 1 is the maximum value meaning its 255. You can use floats to set numbers inbetween 0 and 1, so

```
private Color defaultColor = new Color(30,30,30,255)
```

is actually supposed to be set like

```
private Color defaultColor = new Color(0.13f,0.13f,0.13f,1);
```